# Share javascript sdk not poping up on IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

Inserting the following code does not work on IE7 and IE8. When clicking the link the share dialog should pop up but it does not in these browsers.

```
'<div class="facebookshare-box-wrapper">
   <a href="#"
      onclick="
      window.open(
        \'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=\'+encodeURIComponent(location.href),
        \'facebook-share-dialog\',
        \'width=626,height=436\');
    return false;">
    <span>Share on Facebook</span>
  </a>
</div>'
```

On fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Am4ND/

Comment: Can you please post on JsFiddle so we can test? Do you have an error in the JavaScript console of your browser? Your code seems in a PHP variable, what is `t()`?

Comment: t() is a drupal tranlate function, I now removed it from the html since it really does not make a difference. No extra javascript required. COuld it be an issue of browserstack browser simulators?

Comment: You are trying to use `facebook-share-dialog` as the popup window name – IIRC older IE where really picky about that, and allowed only letters, digits and underscores in there, so your use of `-` in there might be problematic. Try with a simpler name, like `FacebookShareDialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, look at the [result on JsFiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/Am4ND/5/).

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:share();">
    <span>Share on Facebook</span>
</a>

<script>
    function share() {
        window.open(
        "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+encodeURIComponent(location.href),
        "facebooksharedialog",
        "width=626,height=436");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I cleaned and refactored your code, be careful about parameter delimiters.

Comment: This does not work on ie7-9 due to the dashes in 'facebook-share-dialog'

Comment: Sorry I didn't test in all browsers, in this case remove the dashes and that fix your problem. Please check my updated JSFiddle in my answer.